# How delete rows using a variable in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, azure, stored-procedures

Hope you can help me with the issue below.

**DETAILS**: I am trying to create a stored procedure for my Azure Data Factory project where I can pass a variable table name through to tell SQL Server to delete rows.

This all is part of an ERP tool with transactional data. I would delete rows that are in the target, but changed in the source.

**Example**: rowid 1 - €100 in the target but changes in the source later to €80. Then I need to delete that row with €100 in the target and copy the new value from the source with the same rowid to the target

---

I'm migrating from a Oracle environment to a Microsoft environment. In Oracle I've this SQL for the stored procedure:

```html
create or replace procedure AAAAA_delete
as
cursor c_del
is


select 'delete from ' ||table_name ||' a where not exists (select 1 from ' ||replace(table_name,'AAAAA','BBBBB') ||' b where a.rowid = b.rowid)' deletions
from all_tables
where table_name like 'AAAAA%'
and table_name not like 'AAAAA_LOAD%'
and table_name not in ('AAAAA_TIME','AAAAA_CONFIGURATION')
order by 1;

begin
for r_del in c_del
    loop
     execute immediate r_del.deletions;
     commit;
    end loop;
end;
```

** the names have been changed to AAAA and BBBB on purpose to publish the code **

I'm wondering how i can transform this into MS SQL.

**WHY?**: My whole ETL process in Azure Data Factory is based on variables. All the table names etc are stored in a metadata table. And it depends on +- 70 tables.

**QUESTION**: Is it possible to create a generic stored procedure to drop rows  depending on the name I pass through.

Comment: use dynamic sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your code can be adapted for MS SQL;

```
create procedure AAAAA_delete AS
DECLARE @VARA NVARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @EXEC NVARCHAR(1000); 

DECLARE CURSER CURSOR 
  LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR 
    SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    where table_name like 'AAAAA%'
and table_name not like 'AAAAA_LOAD%'
and table_name not in ('AAAAA_TIME','AAAAA_CONFIGURATION')
order by 1

OPEN CURSER
FETCH NEXT FROM CURSER INTO @VARA
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
      SET @EXEC = N'delete from ' +@VARA +' a where not exists (select 1 from ' + replace(@VARA,'AAAAA','BBBBB') +' b where a.rowid = b.rowid)'

      EXEC(@EXEC)

     FETCH NEXT FROM CURSER INTO @VARA
END
CLOSE CURSER
DEALLOCATE CURSER
```